# Acoustic guitar buzzing. Me or the guitar?

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar

looked into this a lot, but I'm unsure what to do. 
I am still a beginner and know about 3 songs haha! But I have played them a lot, I'm at the stage where it's finally not hurting to hold the strings down and when I'm learning something new or taking my time, it sounds great. However I started to notice it buzzing a lot..like everytime I change chord (usually taking my fingers off to change chord) or just random times. I doubted my self at first but looked on this and seen that people were saying the action could be out or maybe the strings, since the strings were new I thought I would find a shop and get it serviced, which included adjusting the truss rod (he said he looked to see if it needed doing but said it looked fine to him)  and new strings. However it seemed okay at first.. not perfect, but it's going back to buzzing all the time.
So now I feel like it's me, but it's getting to the point where my fingers are hurting so from it. I have looked into it and tried everything, but can't seem to find an answer.
Anyway, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: how close are your fingers to the fret (the actual piece of metal)? If you are centered between the frets it may cause buzz. try moving your finger as close to the fret as you can (toward the bridge).

Comment: They are sometimes closer to the middle, but that's when my other fingers are on the same fret. I'm trying to put my finger down harder but it's hurting so much!

Comment: Do the open strings buzz?

Comment: Hmmm, that's a good point. I can check that

Comment: You don't really need to press that hard. I would do this: go one string at a time. Start at fret one and see if you can play a note without it buzzing. Try moving to fret 2. Is there a spot on the guitar, either above a certain fret for all strings or one string in particular that buzzes more? Try to find a fret and string that doesn't buzz. Slowly release pressure until it buzzes. Just a little bit more pressure is all you need. Can you find a problem area by searching the whole guitar like this?

Comment: I didn't think I need to press that hard, but it won't stop and it doesn't half ruin the song. I will do.

Comment: So the problem seem to be my little finger, and I think my finger placement when changing chord. It seems to buzz loads when I come off the chord. I notice it when playing wonderwall, that little bit where yoir two first fingers come off and on for a couple strums

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it too much. It will get better as you play more and your fingers get stronger. Just keep playing. And don't push so hard it hurts. That will just lead to an injury.

Comment: It could be how you are fingering the notes.  But it could also be due to strumming too hard.  You can make any guitar buzz if you over play.  If it's on only certain notes (at certain frets) then the frets may be uneven and need to be files down.  In short there is too little info to ascertain if it's you are the guitar.

Comment: Thanks b3ko. I was worried about my progression you see.

Comment: ggcg, I will try it with a lighter strum, I didn't think of that. How would I determine if the frets are uneven?

Comment: When you took it into the shop for a set up they should have done that (depending on how reliable they are).  They use a metal straight edge to check.  If there is one or two odd frets that stick out a lite filing is usually part of the set up cost.  But if there are dips in the frets from long term wear and tear then the job may cost a bit more, may need new frets all together.

Comment: @JohnMcFadden, http://www.frets.com/FretsPages/Luthier/Technique/Setup/BuzzDiagnosis/UnevenFrets/uneven.html

Comment: I am still new to guitar and music in general but I have been learning both electric and acoustic guitar and I noticed every time I tried to speed thing up i would get clumsy and hit the strings with my fingernails without realizing it.